# find overlapping regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'm using regex to find a pattern

I need to find all matches in this way :

input :"word1_word2_word3_..."

result: "word1_word2","word2_word3", "word4_word5" ..

Comment: And what did you try so far? [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using `(?=)` positive lookahead.

**Regex**: [`(?=(?:_|^)([^_]+_[^_]+))`](https://regex101.com/r/OLpH2Y/1)

Java code:

```
String text = "word1_word2_word3_word4_word5_word6_word7";
String regex = "(?=(?:_|^)([^_]+_[^_]+))";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
     System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
word1_word2
word2_word3
word3_word4
...
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/h0T0eN)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without regex, using [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
    String input = "word1_word2_word3_word4";
    String[] words = input.split("_");
    List<String> outputs = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
        String first = words[i];
        String second = words[i + 1];
        outputs.add(first + "_" + second);
    }

    for (String output : outputs) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```